# Is it possible android/ios Bluetooth block/reject connection request under discoverable mode programmatically?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, request, block

I am writing a android/ios application that detect/search another phone that turned on Bluetooth and get those name and mac address for further functions development. The application will run as background service that keep scanning the Bluetooth device.

Problems:

1. For Android, the phone Bluetooth needs to turn into discoverable mode that can let another phone to scan/detect and get the name and mac address. So, I am worry about that phone user keep requesting to another phone causing disturbance because the connection pair request can let the phone popup a confirm dialog box . Is it possible to block/reject the connection request under discoverable mode programmatically? Phone can scan bluetooth device and can get the information but can not request connection while the application is running.
2. For iOs, there is the same problem, but there is another question that i want to ask. Can Bluetooth keep scanning into background like android background service?
3. Turn off the screen of android devices that the Bluetooth signal still scannable. But iOs devices can not. Is it possible to let iOs Bluetooth device still be scannable when the screen off.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can scan for Bluetooth devices in background (even when device is locked) as long as you add that background capability to your app. Simply start scanning when your app is launched, and don't stop.

However, this uses a significant amount of battery power (scans every 20ms), and even more if there are actual Bluetooth devices nearby (because scan response may be requested).

Instead, take a look at the [Region Monitoring and iBeacon](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html) functionality in the CoreLocation classes. That is meant for power efficient discovery of BLE beacons.

You will not be able to get the MAC addresses on iOS. You will be getting UUIDs.

If the user force kills the app, background scanning stops.